# Comparing column names of different files in R

Tags: r

I have many files in R. I want to compare the col names of each file with a base_file. If all the column names of a particular file matching with the base_file column names print("No Mismatch"). Else report the column name which is not matching

```
base_file <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

file_2 <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)      
## Output expected : No- Mistach

file_3 <- data.frame(col1,col15,col12,col4,col5)  
##  Output expected : No col3, col3. Extra columns col12,col15
```

I want a function for the above like this :

```
fun <- function(base_file,file_2){ }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this function :

```
fun <- function(base_file,file_2) { 
    if(all(names(base_file) %in% names(file_2))) {
      cat('\nNo-Mismatch\n')
      file_2[names(base_file)]
     }
     else {
      cat('\nNo cols : ', setdiff(names(base_file), names(file_2)))
      cat('\nExtra cols : ', setdiff(names(file_2), names(base_file)))
    }
}

fun(df, df1)

#No cols :  b c
#Extra cols :  

fun(df, df2)

#No cols :  b c
#Extra cols :  d
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6, c = 11:15)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 2:3)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, d = 2:4)
```

Comment: I also want to check if the order of the columns is the same in both files or not. If the order is not the same but, both the files have the same columns, the new file should rearrange all its columns in the format as the base_file. For Example df <- data.frame (a=1:5, b= 2:6, c= 11:15) and df1 <- data.frame(b=10:20,c=1:12,a=1:55) . Now these two data frames have same columns but, different ordering. The df1 columns should be arranged in df column order i.e a,b and c.

Comment: @RohanBali I am actually confused about what you are trying to do. I have updated the answer to rearrange the order of the columns based on base file when all the columns match. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.